# Given an implementation of a Service Layer and Repository layer, should you make tests of both?

Tags: java, testing, spring, junit

Currently I have an entity called `Product` with the respective `ProductRepository` and `ProductService`.

For `ProductService`, I have tests for:

- Read (Covering Create too)
- Update
- Delete

Besides achieving higher test coverage, is there any particular reason to also test `ProductRepository`?

What I think:

It could be possible that, one day, `ProductService` gets added complexity that needs to be tested within the previous mentioned tests, giving the `ProductRepository` a perspective of 'testing the most primitive part of the layer' (The CRUD against the database), therefore justifying its testing.

Comment: Does the service do something else besides the functions you have mentioned? Seems like it's simply duplicating the logic of the repository, in which case it seems to be pretty useless.

Comment: Right now? Yes. Basic CRUD with no added transformations or complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at it the comments, your `ProductService` at the moment seems to be an abstraction for the sake of having an abstraction. If you *truly* don't have any `Product`-related business logic, then test `ProductRepository` and just drop `ProductService`.

However, in my experience it's more likely you do have some `Product`-related business logic somewhere and that should be moved into `ProductService`, meaning you want to test them both.

Comment: While `ProductService` still doesn't have any business logic yet, we don't know how (or when) It is going to change. Your answer makes sense. Thank you.